# Working with for loop and jquery load event for multiple images return only the last loaded one props

Tags: jquery, for-loop

I'm working with a `jQuery plug-in` useful to zoom the resized background images with the mouse interaction.

To make it work, I thought to use an `array` of `objects` with the `width` and `height` of a `background-image` of every element I bring to it.

To do this I've created an empty `img` element, set the `src` attribute to the background image, and once it's loaded getting `width` and `height`.

I've thought to handle it starting in a `for loop` which prepares every image, when the jQuery event `load` is called I create the new array element with every info about the loaded image.

It seems the `load` event sets the first loaded image, and apply the same properties to every element loaded after it, how can I avoid this problem?

```
// this is a portion of the plugin

var setImageSize = function (i) {
    return function (e) {
        // I use the extend method only to get different zoom animation if they are added by the user
        instances[i] = {id:i, element:this_obj.get(i), settings:$.extend(true, defaults, options)};
        instances[i].settings.bg.url = getBackgroundUrl(i);
        instances[i].settings.bg.width = parseInt($(this).width());
        instances[i].settings.bg.height = parseInt($(this).height());
        updateDefaultValues(instances[i]);
        $(instances[i].element).hover(setRollOver(i), setRollOut(i));
        $(window).resize(getUpdateDefaultValues(i));
        $('#debug').html($('#debug').html() + 'image loaded: ' + i + ' url:' + instances[i].settings.bg.url +'<br/>width: '+ instances[i].settings.bg.width +' height: '+ instances[i].settings.bg.height +'<br>- - - - - <br>');
        $(this).remove();
    }
}

var prepareImageSize = function (i) {
    var img = $('<img id="jquery-background-zoom-'+i+'"/>');
    img.hide();
    img.bind('load', setImageSize(i));
    $('body').append(img);
    img.attr('src', getBackgroundUrl(i));
}

var init = function () {
    for (var i = 0; i < this_obj.length; i ++) {
        prepareImageSize (i);
    }
}

init();
```

I've reported a full working example here at http://jsfiddle.net/tonino/CFPTa/

In the plug-in I've added a script to see how the images are set, then if you try to interact with the images you'll notice the props of every images are overwritten by the last loaded image, I'm not sure how?

It seems like the load event overwrite previous load event or something, how can I fix it?

Comment: Looking at your jsfiddle, I am not so sure what's not working. You appear to get different sizes for each image... at least based on the display section... what browser are you using?

Comment: the problem starts when you try to interact with images, sorry I didn't mentioned what this plug-in does, it works like a `background-image magnifier`, if you try to go with the mouse on one of the images, you'll notice all the images are treated as the last loaded one

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One thing I notice is you pass options into the init function, but never use them...

I think

```
$.extend(true, defaults, options)
```

isn't doing what you want. That says take options and add it to defaults. You actually want

```
$.extend(true, new Object(), defaults, options)
```

or if you want your code to be less legible you could do it the way they suggest in the jQuery API docs

```
$.extend(true, {}, object1, object2);
```

Comment: fixed! :) forgotten to remove it, now I'm using it directly inside `setImageSize` method as plugin global var

Comment: The case I've written in jsfiddle skip it but it is useful if you want to pass different types of animation and zoom duration, in the case you like to add jquery.animation plug-in for example.

I don't understand why if I go over the first image I get the last image properties in `bg.width` and the other `props`.

After the `$.extend` method I set the `width`, `height` and other params, which are treated as a `single node of the array`, why? where I'm wrong?

Comment: The problem I notice is when go over the `first or second image`, which returns the `width` and the `height` of the `third image`, It's not clear to me why.

Comment: I use `$.extend` to merge the default animation props of defaults with the options I pass in `$('div.image').backgroundZoom (options);` which are empty in this case. The merged data goes into the property `settings` of my `instances array`. This works for me, isn't it?

Comment: Your code above (and in jsfiddle) adds the options to the object held by the variable default, and then returns that object. Default is global (with respect to your code), and so the next time you add the options you go and get the SAME object (the one held by the variable default) and overwite the everything with the info for the next image. The second argument of extend is the TARGET onto which the properties of the third (fourth, etc) object(s) are written.  The target is then returned from the extend function. http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.extend/

Comment: Sorry, now I understand what you mean, I'll try to fix it, thanks for your patience.

Comment: yes it is! thank you very much! now I can continue to fix the code and finish it!